# where to put SSL certs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, ssl, openssl

I'm attempting to encrypt the traffic for my iphone game, and I'm running into a problem. I have a keystore.p12 file, and I want to set it up so the private key is on the server with the public key on the client, so I export the .cer from the .p12 file, but I'm not sure what to put for SecIdentityRef when setting up the sockets.

I want to confirm. I don't want to put the keystore .p12 file on the client do I? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using SSL in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you want to use client side SSL certificates? Is it not enough to simply use either an official purchased SSL certificate on your server or disable the check for official certificates on the device?

Comment: I don't think I need to use client side certificates. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it using the iphone SDK any other way though

Comment: Ignoring self signed certs is well covered on Stack Overflow. Don't have a link for you but it should be easy to find. Or use something more high level like ASIHTTPRequest, which has a simpe flag for dealing with invalid certs.

Answer (score 0):

Using client side-ssl is one of the strongest single forms of authentication.   Unfortunately,  what you are trying to accomplish is fundamentally impossible.  A iPhone user can jailbreak the device and have **more control** over the device than you do.

The only method of truly secure this system is to redesign your application and only expose server-side functionally that safe for an attacker to use.  If this is impossible then your best hope is obfuscation and hoping that no one spends the time to look at your application. This is the wrong approach as it violates [Security Through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).